# Update date in Python

Tags: python

so here is my problem, I am trying to do a little program that gives the user the next date when he will have to pay rent.

Here is my code:

```
curdate = datetime.date(2015, 01, 01)
rent_date = datetime.date(curdate.year, curdate.month+1, 01)

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
one_week = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 1)
one_month = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 4)

def rent_date_calc(cd, rd):
    if cd.month == 12:
        rd.replace(cd.year+1, 01, 01)
    else:
        rd.replace(cd.year, cd.month+1, 01)

def time_pass(rd, cd, a, al):
    if rd < cd:
        for a in al:
            a.finances -= a.rent

move_fwd = raw_input("Would you like to move forward one day(1), one week (2) or one month (3)?")
if move_fwd == "1":
    curdate += one_day
elif move_fwd == "2":
    curdate += one_week
else:
    curdate += one_month

time_pass(rent_date, curdate, prodcomp, prodcomps)
rent_date_calc(curdate, rent_date)
print "Rent date: " + str(rent_date)
```

The problem I have is that rent_date always stays the same (2015-02-01)
Any idea why?

Comment: [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) returns a new date. You are calling `rd.replace`, but not capturing the result. You probably need to return the new date from `rent_date_calc` and print that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not altering anything because datetime is an immutable object, and when you call replace on it, it returns a new datetime, instead of modifying the first one.

You should `return` the new object from the function and `assign` it back to `rent_date`:

```
def rent_date_calc(cd, rd):
    if cd.month == 12:
        return rd.replace(cd.year+1, 01, 01)
    else:
        return rd.replace(cd.year, cd.month+1, 01)

...

rent_date = rent_date_calc(curdate, rent_date)
```

Comment: You're wrelcome. Thanks to @pistache for the explanation. You should [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Your functions have to return a new rent date.** You just need to add the following lines in your code:

- ***return cd***
- ***new_rent_date = rent_date_calc(curdate, rent_date)***

====================================================================

```
curdate = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
rent_date = datetime.date(curdate.year, curdate.month+1, 1)

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
one_week = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 1)
one_month = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 4)


def rent_date_calc(cd, rd):
    if cd.month == 12:
        new_date = rd.replace(cd.year+1, 1, 1)
    else:
        new_date = rd.replace(cd.year, cd.month+1, 1)
    return new_date

def time_pass(rd, cd, a, al):
    if rd < cd:
        for a in al:
            a.finances -= a.rent
        # Not sure what this function should return...

move_fwd = raw_input("Would you like to move forward one day(1), one week (2) or one month (3)?")
if move_fwd == "1":
    curdate += one_day
elif move_fwd == "2":
    curdate += one_week
else:
    curdate += one_month

# time_pass(rent_date, curdate, prodcomp, prodcomps)
new_rent_date = rent_date_calc(curdate, rent_date)
print "Rent date: " + str(new_rent_date)
```

Comment: `cd` and `rd` aren't changes in the function